# Samples generated via VBA code are repetitive

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code to generate samples, but the rows keep repeating the same figure in the first row.

I have attached an excel spreadsheet with the samples and the Macros.

My current macro:

```
Sub PSA_Dist_SampleGenerator()

'Step 1: Assigning a variable to copy iterations for the loop function.
Dim Index As Integer 'Index is to ensure loop function runs up to a specified number of runs.


'Step 2: Altering application settings.
'Setting screen updating off for a fast and crash-proof process.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Setting Excel calculations to 'manual' to decrease the time and processing requirements.
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Step 3: Delete previously sampled/copied values
Sheets("covariance matrices (2)").Select
Range("Header").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents


'Step 4: The loop that will copy the desired number of trials
Index = 1

Do While Index <= Range("Iteration_Number").Value
Application.StatusBar = "Running simulation number: " & Index & ", out of " & 
Range("Iteration_Number").Value & " simulations."
Calculate
Range("Header").Offset(Index, 0).Value = Range("Sampled_Values").Value
Index = Index + 1
Loop

'Step 5: Resetting application settings.
Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

---

Below is an alternative macro that also repeats the first row (code repetitive because trying to condense it resulted in no samples being generated)

---

```
Sub Generate_Samples_PSA()
'
Dim Iterations, n As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Iterations = Range("w2").Value

For n = 1 To Iterations

Calculate
Range("K3:K4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("S4").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=True

Next n

For n = 1 To Iterations
Calculate
Range("L3:L4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("U4").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=True
Next n

For n = 1 To Iterations

Calculate
Range("M3:M4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("W4").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=True

Next n

For n = 1 To Iterations

Calculate
Range("N3:N4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("Y4").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(n, 0).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=True

Next n

End Sub
```

Comment: Which is your problem, in fact? You say "the rows keep repeating the same figure in the first row" like it would be something you do not want. **What do you want** happening? When you try debugging something not working as expected, you must forget about optimization. Please, comment `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`. Then run the code line by line, pressing F8 in VBE and seeing what really happens on the worksheet. If something unexpected happens, move the cursor over the variables and see what is wrong against what you want happening.

Comment: Where did you "attached an excel spreadsheet with the samples and the Macros."? Is your `Range("Sampled_Values").Value` a named range consisting in a single cell? Your code repeats copying it. What do you like copying?

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the first code:
The value is repeated because you are setting all values to `Range("Sampled_Values").Value` try changing the line to

```
Range("Header").Offset(Index, 0).Value = Range("Sampled_Values").Offset(Index, 0).Value
```